# Group a vector of numbers by range

Tags: r

I have a sorted vector:

```
c(1, 10, 31, 80, 100, 120, 160)
```

I would like to split its elements into several groups by range, which I set to 31 in this example.

The result is like this:

```
[[1]] 1, 10, 31
[[2]] 80, 100
[[3]] 100, 120
[[4]] 160
```

The ranges in each group is less than 31. I have tried a loop, but I do not like it. Also, I tried the `outer` function, where I calculated all pairwise differences:

```
res <- outer(vec, vec, "-")
```

Then filter each column by the condition `> 0` and `< 31`.

```
apply(res, 2, function(x) x[x > 0 & x < 31])
```

The result is not good enough though...

Comment: A number can be in 2 groups like 100?

Comment: yes, because the range of 100 and 120 is less than 31 and the range of 80 and  120 is more than 31.

Comment: Do you mean `c(1, 10, 31, 32, 60, 62)` (say) will be in one group only? Or else please tell its desired grouping for range = 31.

Comment: the range is less than 31, so the group will be c(1,10,31), c(31,32,60), c(32,60,62)

Comment: Since you allow repetition why isn't there a group c(10, 31, 32) in the example shared by @AnilGoyal ?

Comment: yes, sorry for that. c(10, 31,32)  is one of the groups

Comment: Have you checked the answer below. I noticed that you have revised your question with the intermediate code I posted earlier. Now the job remains to filter out subsets only. In that case the second code works. Or is there any problem still?

Comment: sorry for leaving a lot of time. I am trying to run the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

I think this will serve your purpose **finally**

First list will extract items fulfilling your condition of range, whereas final_list will remove items that are actually contained in some other items.

```
vec <- c(1, 10, 31, 80, 100, 120, 160)

first_list <- unique(apply(outer(vec, vec, "-"), 1, function(x){vec[(x < 31 & x >= 0)] }))

final_list <- first_list[!sapply(seq_along(first_list), function(i) max(sapply(first_list[-i],function(L) all(first_list[[i]] %in% L))))]

> final_list
[[1]]
[1]  1 10 31

[[2]]
[1]  80 100

[[3]]
[1] 100 120

[[4]]
[1] 160
```

Comment: thanks a lot. I am trying to understand the code

Comment: The code is simple.  First part outputs unique elements of lists fulfilling criteria. Second part removes the subsets if elements contained there in.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a neat solution

```
x <- c(1, 10, 31, 80, 100, 120, 160)
y <- findInterval(x+30, x)
lapply(seq_along(x)[!duplicated(y)], function(z) x[z:y[z]])

#> [[1]]
#> [1]  1 10 31
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1]  80 100
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [1] 100 120
#> 
#> [[4]]
#> [1] 160
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, I am trying to understand it